# UNITY3D ¿Como lograr que un objeto se mantenga a una cierta distancia de otro objeto?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Tengo dos naves en UNITY, llamemoslas A y B:

La nave A se mueve de manera constante hacía adelante.

La nave B tiene que perseguir a la nave A, acercándose a ella y rotando alrededor de ella pero a una cierta distancia.

El esqueleto básico del funcionamiento es el siguiente:

```
private void()
{
    Move();
    Turn();
}
```

Para que B persiga a A utilizo este código:

```
private void Move()
{
    transform.position += transform.forward * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime + target.transform.position;
}
```

Que se encuentra en un método llamado Move al cual invoco en Update.
Tambien tengo otro método llamado Turn que se encarga de las rotaciones:

```
private void Turn()
{
    Vector3 pos = target.transform.position - transform.position;
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(pos);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, rotationalDamp * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer, para que a partir de cierta distancia, la nave B no se acerqué mas  a la nave A y se mantenga rotando (como orbitando) a su alrededor?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: utiliza dos mesh colllider inabilitalos y crea una escepcion entre los dos objetos si es en linea recata utiliza varios box collider asi evitas que cree una circuferencia....

Answer (score 0):

Lo condicionas.
Ejemplo

```
if(pos <= 0.5f)
 {
   //Rotar en su orbita
 }
else if (pos > 0.5f)
 {
   //Seguir a nave A
 }
```

De esta manera no lo seguira si esta en su distancia minima, y en vez de seguirlo procedera a rotar.